# select four tables in zend framework 2 query

Tags: mysql, zend-framework2

```
SELECT * FROM tab1 union select * from tab2 union select * from tab3 union select * from tab4;
```

I want to convert this query into ZF2 query

I tried

```
$sql->select()
    ->from(array('a' => 'tab1', 'b' => 'tab2', 'c' => 'tab3', 'd' => 'tab4'));
```

but query didn't work, i want to union all four tables

Comment: In ZF2, you have `combine()` for doing the `union`. Check for it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is not a direct way to get the desired sql query formed using `combine()` too.

But there is a work around to get the same result set.

Try this -

```
$select1 = $sql->select('tab1');
$select2 = $sql->select('tab2');
$select1->combine($select2);

$select3 = $sql->select('tab3');

$selectall3 = $sql->select();
$selectall3->from(array('sel1and2' => $select1));
$selectall3->combine($select3);

$select4 = $sql->select('tab4');

$selectall4 = $sql->select();
$selectall4->from(array('sel1and2and3' => $selectall3));
$selectall4->combine($select4);
```

Now use `$selectall4` for executing the statement.

This will give you the same result as your desired query -

`SELECT * FROM tab1 
union select * from tab2 
union select * from tab3 
union select * from tab4;`

Answer (score 0):

you can find your solution here

http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.db.select.html#zend.db.select.building.union